# What is the best way for rendering a huge voxel object?

Tags: opengl, 3d, rendering, 3d-modelling

I am trying to display 3d model of a human in opengl. The human object is represented by a 3D array[n][n][n] (height, width and depth), where n = 300. Each element of array has value either 1 or 0. If element is 0 then it should be ignored else drawn.

Problem: due to the fact that I have to iterate through 3D array using 3 nested for loops and then create vertices for each individual voxel it takes a lot of time.

My idea of how to solve the problem: write another program that would iterate through array, create vertices and write them to the file. And then whenever I need to render I would read vertices from the file.

Question: What is the best way to render such an object? Would be great if you could suggest any algorithm or technic.

Comment: Try searching for `"opengl volume rendering"`.  Also `"isosurface generation"` and `"marching cubes"`.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I made a school project where I did something similar.

I had a 3D volume representation with 0s and 1s which represents a room. 0 means the cube is empty, 1 means the cube is full. It's the same problem you are facing but flipping the normal of the quads.

[image]

So I made an algorithm that turns the cube of bits into the minimum number of quads.

I've been digging in my old code repository and found the [function that does that](https://bitbucket.org/tuket/cadcam-portal/src/1da3f4e6684887c9a6fe740498b44965d2075fa4/cube_of_bits.cpp#lines-354). I feel a bit ashamed of the code I wrote back then, but hopefully you can grab some inspiration from it.

I'm going to try to give a brief explanation of what the algorithm does.

- We slice the volume with planes in each direction X, Y and Z.
- For each plane we check all the cells it touches on each side.
- If both sides have the same number (both 0, or both 1), we do nothing.
- Otherwise (we have a different number on each side), we generate a quad in that position, and the normal of that quad will depend on the order of the numbers (01 or 10).
- Ignore the colorCount variable, I think it's just a color ID I used for debugging.

My program called this algorithm when it first loads, and whenever you make a change in the scene (it was a live-editor). I didn't notice any slowdowns when editing the scene and the computer I was using back then was not very fast.